# Why am I getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: remoteWindow is not defined"

Tags: ember.js

I'm suddenly getting this error in my Ember app. Nothing shows up:

```
DEPRECATION: Action handlers contained in an `events` object are deprecated in 
favor of putting them in an `actions` object (error on <Ember.Route:ember###>)

Error while loading route: TypeError {} 

Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
...
}

Uncaught ReferenceError: remoteWindow is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

It might be due to the update of Ember Data to the latest 1.0 version in September 2013. So you have to use

```
this.store.find('model');
```

Instead of

```
App.Model.find();
```

[And make more changes based on this document](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#defining-relationships-in-models).

#### 2.

Add `actions` in controller, [see this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511458/action-handlers-implemented-directly-on-controllers-are-deprecated-how-to-corre).